# PHP Json decoder returns NULL if it contains & or é or special characters

Tags: php, json

I'm wondering how to escape these special characters for the php built-in json decoder to understand, and what are these characters?

Example: `json_decode('{"text":"test & test"}',true);`

Returns `NULL`

I try to use `\` to escape it but it doesn't work ( only works for quotes ).

Any solution?

Comment: That JSON seems to be fine; except `"`, `\‍`, and control characters any Unicode character is allowed in a JSON string.

Comment: [Works for me.](http://pastie.org/1350172) What does your actual PHP code look like?

Comment: [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) expects the input to be encoded in UTF-8. Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

It should work with using plain & it works for me so ... , however i had problems in the past with with stings that didn't recognize some special characters , the solution in that case was to make shure that the php file document encoding was set to utf8 . Another problem i had in the past was with XMLReader witch didn't accept a plain simple & but `&amp;` instead works just fine so you could try the following :

```
json_decode(preg_replace('/&/','&amp;','{"text":"test & test"}'));
```

p.s. i suppose you're trying to decode a larger json string so the problem might come from a different part of the string , did you run the exact test you posted in the question and it returned null ?